# What are the main pointers to creating a written template of a fantasy world?

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process

I only have what I consider the "basics" of worldbuilding. I have government settled, religion settled, transportation/trade, military, and climate/weather patterns. I'm making this template for the purpose of keeping myself organized. Is there anything else I need to mention?

Answer (score 3):

I believe, having spoken to different individuals who were creating fantasy worlds for stories, that your base notes will have different requirements based on the story your writing and how you write. As such, the answer largely depends. Some people begin with the plot and work through the kinks as they show up. Others, like you, start with a world and tailor the plots to them. In my own experience, I find that plots are best built around a world, and the best way to build a world is to define its history.

I'm assuming here that since you're starting with a world definition, you are going to tailor the plot to this. That assumed, you need to define three things:

1) What are the defining characteristics of your world (what makes it different from the one we have and from other fantasy worlds)

2) The time of your definition (where you are in the history of your world)

3) The history that got you there (the timelines|stories|event-chains|cultural-systems that lead to a certain outcome)

You have definitions for Government, Religion, Societal Infrastructure, Martial Structure, and the Meteorological conditions. **The main question you need to be asking to know if you've got enough is if your world has been differentiated from the normal one and from others in the way's that are significant to your vision/plot.** You then define the point in time at which you are entering this world and build your history to meet your criteria.

In a nutshell, the gauge for having enough base material or not is to **ask whether your world is differentiated from the normal or template world in the right ways** to meet your vision. If your current definitions meet that vision, then your all set. If not, you may need to rethink what is important to make this world different, and work from there.